# Expression Engine Database Structure

Tags: codeigniter-2, expressionengine

I am maintaining a website built in ExpressionEngine.
Issue: When the site was built, in the channel administration, one main category was added "main_category", and under it about 250 categories and sub categories which resulted in a massive table "exp_channel_data" consisting of nearly 500 columns.

I know this was an end-user design flaw when creating categories but the question is:
What will it take to move all the categories and sub-categories out of that root category?
There are few thousand articles assigned to the current categories.

Any toughs?
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about _categories_, or _fields_? Categories do not affect `exp_channel_data` in any way - 500 columns in that table indicates hundreds of custom fields (each field gets two columns, `field_id_XX` and `field_ft_XX`).

Comment: Thanks Derek but the data itself such as content and articles are stored in exp_channel_data, is that right?

Comment: Yes, `exp_channel_data` stores most of your content.